# Check if array contains certain key using switch case

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement, key

The question is as the title says. I need to check if an array contains a certain key in a switch case. I need to use a switch case as I need to check for more than 3 elements. I'm confused how to go about this.

For example.

```
$update = array();
$update['message'] = array('photo' => array(array('file_id' => 1234, 'file_size' => 3451), array('file_id' => 64254, 'file_size'=>51235)));
```

I need to check if the array $update['message'] contains a key called 'photo' (and other elements as well which is why I need a switch clause)
If anyone could point out how this is done correctly, it would be much appreciated.

I know i can go about doing this with nested if statements but that is not so clean and efficient.

**UPDATE :**
**I've arrived at a solution, although it works I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it. Suggestions would be appreciated.**

It is as follows

```
switch($update['message'])
{
case (array_key_exists('photo', $update['message'])): echo 'hello'; break;
default:break;
}
```

Comment: You mean like `in_array()`? No wait, this would be `array_key_exists()` wouldn't it.

Comment: Ive arrived at  solution, ive updated the question. Please take a look :)

Comment: "I need to use a switch case as i need to check for more than 3 elements." You mean the array can only contain one of the 3 keys? Switch case won't catch if it contains all 3. It will just detect the one you put first in the switch case.

Comment: yes, one of x number of keys that i look for.

Comment: Is it possible for `$update['message']` to ever have more than one of the keys?

Comment: No, it'll only contain one key

Comment: What is the original problem you want to solve? It is hard to understand how is your example is more efficient than another solution because we don't know what you are solving.

Comment: what i mean is 
`switch($update['message'])`  
now this is okay if i were to check for the value of the 'message' key in $update array but since im looking for a key rather than the value of a key i just want to know if this is an okay practice

Comment: $update['message'] is an array, array_key_exists('photo', $update['message']) is a boolean value. Your code works only because $update['message'] is a non-empty array and it casts to true. So it is hard to understand what you wanted to achieve to give you any advice.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```
switch(array_key_exists('photo', $update['message']))
{
    case true: echo 'hello'; break;
    default:break;
}
```

Comment: That is the same as an if else statement :)